# Not access to internet

Tags: networking, internet, iptables, iwlwifi

Yesterday I was watching a video and the connection dropped down in my Ubuntu 18.04. I tried connecting to the mobile phone data and with another wifi and it doesn´t work. I also tried with cable and it didn´t work.

I can ping my router but I cannot ping outside, the message error is: "ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted". On chrome I have "dns_probe_finished_no_internet ".

I have tried  iptables -F and it doesn´t resolve (even temporally). As I don´t have access to internet, I cannot copied the ifconfig or the dsmeg (which gives me errors in the ACPI, "iwlwifi bios contains wgds but no wrds", and in certificate x.509).

I am in the need of a quick answer so I would appreciate any help, even some online consultancy if you are aware of.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use NordVPN?

Comment: Hi, not I had already disabled windscribe but I don't know why it still had an entry on the iptable. Eventhough I reset the iptable, when I just navigate it was overwriten. Finally I just dekete the windscribe and did a iptable -F and it is working. Thanks